# how can I edit the instance suffix in an instances group?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sdk, gce-instance-group

My Instances Group automatically add a random suffix to my instances.

I would like to change the instances names or the suffixes in an instances group of GCP. I would prefer a numbered suffix.

Is it possible to do that?

[Screenshot of my Google Cloud in the Instances Group section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7iMK.png)

Comment: Consider to accept/upvote the answer if it solved your issue

Comment: Stackoverflow don't allow me upvote your answer with less than 15 reputation. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to control the suffix for instances belonging to instances group. As you can read in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-groups/managed/create) even making use of the SDK with the optional flags you can change the `base-name` of the instance but no hints regarding the suffix.

```
--base-instance-name=BASE_INSTANCE_NAME

The base name to use for the Compute Engine
instances that will be created with the managed instance group. 
If not provided base instance name will be the prefix of instance group name.
```

Moreover it is not possible to rename Compute Engine instances once they are already been created.
Here you can find an [UserVoice](https://googlecloudplatform.uservoice.com/forums/302595-compute-engine/suggestions/10641504-renaming-vm?page=1&per_page=20) Topic Regarding this feature.